# Batch update using Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to have batch update query However each update Query is different but running on the same table. The Where clause is the same.

For example :

TABLE : Column A,B,C,D,ID

```
update A where ID=1 
update B,C where ID=1
update D,B where ID=1 and so on ... ( all the combinations of A,B,C,D)
```

I have investigated spring jdbc (JDBCTemplate and JDBCNamedParameter ) and QueryDsl but its not possible to have such updates.

Is there any other method by which such update as batch is possible ? I have stick to Spring-JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use a prepared statement passing in the arguments for each update? If so, it's not possible to do this as a batch. You could batch multiple statements, but then you would have to create these statements without using placeholders for the arguments. In this scenario you would use the `int[] JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String[] sql)` method ([http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String:A-](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String%3aA-)).

It's not possible to batch different prepared statements using the JDBC API. You can batch individual statements without arguments ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29)) or batch multiple sets of arguments for a prepared statement ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29)), but the SQL statement would have to be the same for all sets of arguments.

You can still wrap multiple update calls in a transaction, but there would be multiple roundtrips to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your update with a stored proc, then you can batch round trips to the database.

Inside the stored proc you'll need to generate the update based on the arguments passed in.  So you could test for null, or pass a separate flag for each column.  If the flag is set, then generate SQL that updates that column.